# Tensorflow/Keras performance better with less GPU memory?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, keras, gpu

Reducing GPU memory allocation ***increases*** the training speed of my CNN model. I expected the opposite - that speed should *decrease* with allocated memory. I suspect this has to do with time required for transferring data in and out of the GPU.

I ran cases with allocating a) all GPU memory and b) approximately half (46%) of GPU memory. Using all GPU memory (no restriction) training speed is 153 epochs/hour. When allocating 46% of GPU memory, training speed is 199 epochs/hour.

I set GPU memory via:

```
gpu_memory_fraction = 0.46 # Values tested: 0.46 and 1    
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
if gpu_memory_fraction < 1.0:
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = gpu_memory_fraction
    K.tensorflow_backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

I use the keras `model.fit()` method for training. Batch size = 64.

Environment:

- python 3.7.5
- keras 2.2.4
- tensorflow 1.15.0
- conda 4.7.12
- CUDA 10.2
- Nvidia driver 440.44
- Ubuntu 18.04.3
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 1080Ti, 11GB memory
- CPU Intel i9-9900K 3.6 GHz, RAM 64 GB, SSD 120 GB

Can anyone offer an explanation?

Comment: Strange.... I can "imagine" (of course this is a total guess) that as long as you have the minimum size for the graph you're running with that batch size, the rest of the memory is just not used. I don't think the data transfered increases, but maybe the data "cleaning" between batches does?